# Trouble validating whether auth::user() has object through a custom function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to verify whether authenticated user liked the post (or link).

I have a `like` model with `user_id`, `likeable_id` and `likeable_type` (because user should be able to like a post or link which are two seperate models)

In the `App\User.php`:

```
public function likes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
}

public function likedCustom($str) {
    $likedCustom = new Collection();
    $this->likes()->where([
        'likeable_type' => $str,
    ])->each(function ($like) use ($likedCustom) {
        $likedCustom->push($like->likeable);
    });

    return is_null($likedCustom) ? false: $likedCustom;
}

public function likedEntries() {
    $likedEntries = $this->likedCustom('post');
    $links = $this->likedCustom('link');
    $links->each(function ($link) use ($likedEntries) {
        $likedEntries->push($link);
    });

    return is_null($likedEntries) ? false: $likedEntries;
}
```

This is working perfectly fine since I set `App\Post` to `'post'` and `App\Link` to `'link'`. After this when I use `php artisan tinker` I am able to get all the posts and links in one collection as `$entries`. So running `App\User::find(1)->likedEntries()->contains(App\Post::find(1));` returns `true`.

Problem starts here as I try to implement this function on the view. For instance if a post or link is liked by the authenticated user:

```
@foreach ($entries as $entry)
    @if ( Auth::user()->likedEntries()->contains($entry) )
        <li class="active"> {{ $entry->title }} </li>
    @else
        <li> {{ $entry->title }} </li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

So I guessed it can be cause of objects returning differenty. Since I return them this way in `ViewComposers\EntryComposer.php`:

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    // $test = Post::all();
    $entries = Post::all();
    $links = Link::all();
    $links->each(function ($link) use ($entries) {
        $entries->push($link);
    });
    $entries = $entries->sortByDesc(function($entry) {
        return $entry->score();
    });
    $view->with('entries', $entries);
    // $view->with('entries', $test); // Didn't work either.
}
```

What am I missing?

Also:

```
Psy Shell v0.8.12 (PHP 7.1.10 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> App\User::find(1)->likedEntries()
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#754
     all: [
       App\Post {#780
         id: "1",
         title: "debitis",
         body: "Quis rerum amet saepe eligendi. Ullam ea consectetur rerum rem repellat qui qui vel. Aspernatur officiis aut tenetur est perspiciatis harum.",
         user_id: "144",
         category_id: "3",
         created_at: "2017-10-23 12:38:34",
         updated_at: "2017-10-23 12:38:34",
       },
       App\Link {#781
         id: "1",
         title: "Numquam consequuntur minima sunt aut vel facilis deleniti et.",
         url: "https://www.dibbert.info/qui-voluptate-ratione-aperiam-et-ullam-perferendis-et",
         user_id: "136",
         category_id: "2",
         created_at: "2017-10-23 12:38:36",
         updated_at: "2017-10-23 12:38:36",
       },
     ],
   }
>>>  App\User::find(1)->likedEntries()->contains(App\Post::find(1))
=> true
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out at [Polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations), it will simplify a lot the relation logic and that 2 custom functions you have for getting the liked objects from the user.

Any way, you need to do a `->get()` after performing a `->where()` on a query

```
public function likedCustom($str) {
    return $this->likes()->where('likeable_type', $str)->get()->map(function ($like) {
        return $like->likeable;
    });
   // This will return a Collection that can be empty, so you 
   // should check against $collection->isEmpty() or ->count()
}
```

Comment: Thanks but, the code I wrote is working there. Using where()->get() never seems to work for me in tihs situation (returning null) I edit the first post on the end.

Comment: I think problem might be the way I implement sorting them by their score:
```$entries = App\Post::all(); $links = App\Link::all();
$links->each(function($like) use($entries) {
    $entries->push($link);
});
$sortByScore = $entries->sortByDesc(function($entry) {
    return $entry->score();
});```